# Variables in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

When you declare a variable inside a process in VHDL, if you also initialise it to a certain value, i.e. a 0 or a 1, does this variable's value from previous iterations get 're-initialised' to the value you have given it?

For example every time this process is enabled by the change in the 10MHz clock, does the variable shift be initialised to 1, like the image below?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should add a code snippet or so to make the question clear.

Comment: @MituRaj Just added an image

Comment: No. Simple answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example every time this process is enabled by the change in the 10MHz clock, does the variable shift be initialised to 1, like the image below?

No, it's an *initialization* (only for RTL simulation purpose). It will happen only once just before the simulation starts at time 0. The value of the variable, thereafter, depends on what value `process` drives the variable to, inside its logic (description within `begin` to `end`), every time when the `process` is triggered by  events of `Ten_MHz_Clock`.

For synthesis, these initial values are ignored by most synthesisers (I have noticed Vivado and Altera synthesisers support them on FPGA platforms), so it may not be a good coding practice for synthesisable and portable RTL, as there is a chance of synthesis-simulation mismatch at netlist level.

Comment: The word "simulation" needs to be highlighted here. For synthesis, initial values are ignored, so there needs to be an explicit reset mechanism.

Comment: yea, true......

Comment: I always thought that the initialization values were for simulation and synthesis, that is very good to know.

Comment: So on hardware this 'shift' variable in the snippet above will be initialised as a 0?

Comment: No not necessarily. Depends on the tool you use.